# Nested flexbox align-items center specific content

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to build the simple form below.

[image]

I'm using flexbox and having trouble aligning the textarea properly. `align-items: center` aligns the whole div. I've tried taking the textarea div out and am having trouble aligning the textarea relative to the above flexbox container. How can I acheive the above textbox position while having the x, photo, name and aligned centered.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rospq5v5/4/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
img {
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    x
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Brad</div>
    <div>Boston</div>
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap; /* we force a wrap so textarea is in the next line*/
}
.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
textarea {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  margin-left:80px; /* use margin to adjust, change this value depending the icon and image width */
}
img {
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>
    x
  </div>
  <!-- better remove the div around the image, it's useless and avoid having a white space issue -->
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Brad</div>
    <div>Boston</div>
  </div>
  <!-- we make it out of content -->
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: i was trying to avoid setting a margin with a specific pixel number

Comment: @user2954587 i will try to think about another way then :) but i guess the image and the icon will have a known width so it won't be a big issue ;)

Comment: fair point. it seems to be working fine but if you can come up with another solution that'd be pretty cool :)

Answer (score 6):

### CSS Grid

For a simple and efficient solution use Grid Layout. No need to set any fixed widths.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;  /* optional; implicit rows are auto by default */
  grid-template-areas:  "close  avatar   name    "
                        "   .     .     textbox ";
}

.container > *:nth-child(1) { grid-area: close; }
.container > *:nth-child(2) { grid-area: avatar; }
.container > *:nth-child(3) { grid-area: name; }
.container > *:nth-child(4) { grid-area: textbox; }

img {
  vertical-align: top; /* remove descender space applied to inline-level elements */
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.container > * {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>x</div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Brad</div>
    <div>Boston</div>
  </div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

### Flexbox

If you want to stick with flexbox, here's one method, but it requires more details to render properly.

- Allow the container to wrap items (`flex-wrap: wrap`)
- Force the textarea onto its own row (e.g. `flex-basis: 100%`)
- Define a width for the "x" and the avatar
- Subtract the width of the x & avatar from the textarea width
- Left-align the textarea with an auto margin

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.container > div:nth-child(-n + 2) {
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container > div:nth-child(3) {
  flex: 1;
}

img {
  display:block;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

textarea {
  margin-left: auto;
  flex: 0 0 calc(100% - 120px);
}

.container > * {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>x</div>
  <div>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div>Brad</div>
    <div>Boston</div>
  </div>
  <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

---